# Facebook API (me/home) returns the empty array at 3rd call

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using `Facebook API` to get the user timeline entries with time based paging (limit & until) in my `iOS app.`
When i use this API 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=100&until='

The first two call get success and i got 100 entries each.
But when i hit the third call, it returns the empty array like,

```
{
"data":
[]
}
```

I am using `SLRequest` to do the paging.

Note: This flow is working correctly in `Graph API Explorer` tool (Facebook tool). If i changed to my app instead of `Graph API Explorer` app in application selection tab in that tool, the same is replicated.
Do i need to change any app settings in the `Facebook app` regarding the paging?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks